# WordPress - Backup/clone help

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, backup, plugin-wordpress, domínio

Eu estrou fazendo um trabalho que o cliente exigiu que seu site continue online e do mesmo jeito até que todas as alterações sejam feitas. Como posso fazer isso ?? Teria que usar outro domínio?? Eu gostaria de trocar o tema mas tenho medo de que o site não volte como antes.

Fiz o teste do tema utilizando o plugin THEME TEST DRIVE e o site deu uma leve falha no css na hora de voltar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis o que eu faria

1. Fazer um clone/backup do banco de dados
2. Criar outro banco com os dados clonados
3. Duplicar (copiar e colocar) toda a instalação do WP para outra pasta ex `/public_html/novo`
4. Alterar no `wp-config.php` para apontar o bando de dados para o banco clonado.
5. Corrigir os possiveis erros que vai ter por causa da URL, basicamente um link assim `http://meudominio.com.br/nome-do-post` teria que ficar `http://meudominio.com.br/novo/nome-do-post`. Claro que isso vai mudar de acordo com o lugar onde colocou a copia. O [wp-cli](http://wp-cli.org/) pode ajudar bastante, não so nisso mas em outras coisas tambem.
6. Nesse ponto voce deve ter uma copia do site funcionando independente, ai pode fazer suas alterações e testes sem afetar o site atual.